# Two-source interference pattern destructive areas when wave has two-signed magnitude

Tags: electromagnetism, interference, superposition

1.I am trying to understand two-source interference pattern. I am using [this simulation](https://javalab.org/en/youngs_double_slit_en/) for clarity.

As I understand, considering in classic-terms electromagnetic wave has both positive and negative magnitudes, i.e. its electric and magnetic components changes its values from some negative to some positive.

Due to superposition, negative and positive waves with same amplitude should cancel each other.

So, if consider em wave, as wave, that has negative values, as well as positive, we will have the next illustration:

[image]

In all interference (or diffraction) illustrations, explanations or simulations, (for example, like I mentioned above) I found, wave lines are colored same color, that is confusing me. Maybe they are considered wave as one-signed oscillation process?

However, if to consider waves as two-signed oscillation with positive and negative values, known two-source interference pattern seems to be partially wrong. How it should be:

[image]

From illustration above (if drew it correctly, maybe I missed something) we see, that, indeed, middle interference is constructive, **but** each second interference (every even interference) (in both direction from the middle one), should be destructive, because there occurs superposition of waves opposite magnitudes.

And on the screen, as I drew it in the right side of illustration, we should have at center higher value (sum of two waves), then in both direction, lower value (one wave) and not zero (!), then zero (sum of two opposite waves), then lower value (one wave) and all again. After wave half period - all the same, but with opposite sign.

Where do I wrong?

2.One more little question: do I understand correctly, that experiment with one source and two-split obstacle is more "popular" instead of just two monochromatic sources, because it is hard to make them coherent?

---

Well, I searched more images, that illustrates interference, like [this](https://cdn.savemyexams.co.uk/cdn-cgi/image/w=1920,f=auto/uploads/2020/09/8.2.2.2-Water-waves-interference-fringes.png), which seems to be correct, but at the same time [this](https://spark.iop.org/sites/default/files/media/images/two-slit-interference-fringes.gif) image illustrates each interference as constructive, as well as simulation, that mentioned at the beginning of this post.

So, it seems that they are either wrong, either consider waves as only with one sign, or has wrong scale between interference and detector pictures.

Comment: As a general comment: linear systems are "special" because they do not have self-interaction. Waves from different sources are simply passing through each other without changing their shape and without exchanging energy. So what we are calling "interference" is actually the absence of the scattering that is present in all non-linear systems. That is very easily overlooked while one is learning about waves in linear media for the first time. Thinking about interference as "non-interaction" is hard and it takes getting used to.

Comment: "magnitude" is always positive, by definition, so when you say "waves of opposite magnitude", it's not correct. It's better to say "opposite phase (and equal magnitude)". The concept of "positive" and "negative" values is also coordinate dependent (that is: has no physical meaning), and again, it's better to consider phase.

Comment: @JEB, it is not my native language, but as far as I know, magnitude exactly means current value, while amplitude means maximum value, independently on sign (if symmetrical). Or something like that

Comment: To truly understand "interference" of light you should consider Feynman and Dirac statements that explain that each photon does its own thing ... photons never cancel that's violation of conservation of energy.  Photons take certain paths that have path lengths that are typically multiple of the wavelength ... see Feynman path integral on this site.  Dark areas no energy/photons ... light areas get all the photons.

Comment: @PhysicsDave, I think it would be better to start from classic consideration, and then quantum

Comment: Yes the classic is good but has some obvious weakness.  But if we consider that the virtual fields (virtual photons) are just as important as the real photons .... then the classical model applies very well to the virtual field ..... we do not have to worry about energy conservation ..... just sums of fields.

Comment: @PhysicsDave, yeah I've been "learning" about virtual photons and stuff around that, capturing small amounts of knowledge from different areas, and as result have not understood anything specific - just all, in general. So, now I decided to focus on step-by-step learning

Comment: Learning is great.  About superposition: water waves superimpose nicely, but when 2 opposite water waves collide the water looks flat! .... but only for a second and then the waves reemerge .... where was the energy when it was flat? .... the answer is the energy was stored in the medium (water) as elastic energy!   In a friction less world energy is never lost in the medium (ex. water, air, EM field) .... energy is only lost when absorption happens .... water crashes on the beach, sound makes the hairs move on your ear, photons absorbed by atoms/electrons.

Comment: When learning about light and interference ..... many classical ideas are taught today .... but it all dates back to early 1900s ...all the 1st year text books are not so modern!  Only the classical is still taught until maybe a QM course in university ... but even then many old QM principles are learned.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider two coherent sources or two holes or slits does not matter.
In your picture red is the pos max and blue the negative max, so you have constructive interference where two same colors meet and destructive when two different colors cross. At the point where two pos max cross you have a little T/2 later two negativ,the two oscillation  at the points always add up to an oscillation with double amplitude.  Where positive and negative meet it is always zero amplitude. What you write outside the picture is not clear.
With 2) you are right, if the wave is light, for sound one uses two loudspeakers.

Comment: "...constructive interference where two same colors meet and **negative** when..." - did You mean destructive instead of negative?